# Jacobi's alghoritm for SVD

Tags: c, svd, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have a final project, I'm triying to do the SVD for images compression, I tried to compute the singular values of AA^{T} and A^{T}A, I think it gets fine the values, but not in the  orden necessary for the decomposition,

```
void jacobi_mat(double** A, int dim, int N, double tol){
    double a_ij; //greatest value in the matrix (absolute value)
    int index_i, index_j; //index a_ij
    double theta;//rotation angle
    //rotation's matrix 
    double** S = crear_matrix(dim, dim);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        S[i][i] = 1;
    }
    

    int k = 0; //iterations
    //matrix withe the eigenvalues 
    double** A_i = crear_matrix(dim,dim);//crear matriz if to create matrix with dimenssion dim, dim 
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++){
            A_i[i][j] = A[i][j];
        }
    }

    
    while (k < N){
        k++;
        find_greatest(A_i,&a_ij,&index_i,&index_j, dim); //update a_ij
        if(a_ij <= tol){
            break;
        }
        if(A_i[index_i][index_i]==A_i[index_j][index_j]){
            theta = M_PI/4;
        }
        else{
        theta = (0.5)*atan(2*(A_i[index_i][index_j]/(A_i[index_i][index_i]-A_i[index_j][index_j])));//update rotation angle 
        }
        mat_S(A_i,theta,index_i, index_j,dim); // A_i*S = B_i
        mat_Sinv(A_i,theta, index_i, index_j, dim);// S^{-1}* B_{i} = C_i
        mat_S(S,theta, index_i,index_j,dim); //S_i* S_i+1
    }
}
```

where

```
void find_greatest(double** A, double* a_ij, int* index_i, int* index_j,int dim){
    *index_i = 0,*index_j = 0; //save index i,j
    *a_ij = -INFINITY; 
    for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++){
            if(*a_ij< fabs(A[i][j]) && (i!=j)){  
                *a_ij = fabs(A[i][j]);
               *index_i = i; //
                *index_j = j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
void mat_S(double** A_i, double theta, int index_i, int index_j, int dim){
    double temp, temp2; 
    for (int  i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        temp= (A_i[i][index_i]*cos(theta)) + (A_i[i][index_j]*sin(theta)); 
        temp2 = (-A_i[i][index_i]*sin(theta)) + (A_i[i][index_j]*cos(theta));
        A_i[i][index_i]  = temp; 
        A_i[i][index_j] = temp2;
    }    
}


void mat_Sinv(double** A_i, double theta, int index_i, int index_j, int dim){
    double temp, temp2;
    for (int  i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        temp = (A_i[index_i][i]*cos(theta) )+(A_i[index_j][i]*sin(theta)); 
        temp2 = (-A_i[index_i][i]*sin(theta))+(A_i[index_j][i]*cos(theta));
        A_i[index_i][i] = temp;
        A_i[index_j][i] = temp2;
    }  
}
```

What Can I do to sort from the greatest to the smallest eigenvalue? I have to do my SVD descomposition I can't use libraries

Comment: You can [search the Internet](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=c+sort) for sorting algorithms. Choose one which you are allowed to use.

Comment: For sorting, you may use `qsort()` present standard C library. BTW where are eigen values stored?

Comment: @kiner_shah in S, if I sort the values i have to sort of  the matrix with eigenvalue too no?